# Errors running Pandas Profile Report

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-profiling

I'm trying to run a Profile Report for EDA in conda Jupyter NB, but keep getting errors.
Here is my code thus far:

```
    import pandas_profiling
    from pandas_profiling import ProfileReport

    profile = ProfileReport(data)
```

and

```
    profile = pandas_profiling.ProfileReport(data)
```

both of which produce:

> TypeError: concat() got an unexpected keyword argument 'join_axes'

Research recommended upgrading to Pandas 1.0, which I'm using.

Also tried

```
    data.profile_report()
```

> AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'profile_report'

Any tips on where I am going wrong?

Addendum...So I finally figured it out. Needed to install latest version of pandas-profiling in conda, which was 202003 version. Too easy.

Comment: Please do not forget to answer your own question now that you found the solution ;)!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Installed most recent version (March 2020) of pandas-profiling in conda.

```
conda install -c conda-forge/label/cf202003 pandas-profiling
```

Was then able to `import pandas_profiling` in jupyter notebook

Answer (score 11):

First I tried just running the command !pip install pandas-profiling  but still was not working but then I found this **!pip install pandas-profiling==2.7.1**
command, now it is working for me.

Answer (score 2):

This works with the latest release of pandas profiling as well.

Release date - 14th April, 2020.

Find the link to install the same.

https://pypi.org/project/pandas-profiling/

Answer (score 2):

Also running into the same issue. I upgraded using
`pip3 install pandas_profiling --upgrade`

Answer (score 2):

#update Profiling to latest Version first

```
import sys
!{sys.executable} -m pip install -U pandas-profiling[notebook]
!jupyter nbextension enable --py widgetsnbextension

import pandas as pd
from pandas_profiling import ProfileReport

train = pd.read_csv("train.csv")
```

#Generate the profile report

```
report = ProfileReport(train)

print(repr(report.report))

report.to_widgets()
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is  generally with the previous versions of Pandas-Profiling, try upgrading it to a newer version

If you are using google collab
`!pip3 install pandas_profiling --upgrade`

Otherwise use
`$ pip3 install pandas_profiling --upgrade`

After executing this  restart runtime

Answer (score -2):

Execute below command and once completed restart the runtime

```
!pip install pandas-profiling==2.7.1
```